# readxl not reading specific sheets

Tags: r, readxl

I've been using code to read different sheets of the same excel file. It's all been working fine up until a few hours ago. Using the same code (shown below) that has worked countless times, I am now getting an error message saying "Error: `path` does not exist: ‘data/GTSurveyCoded with financial status-2.xlsx’". The package will load my first sheet, even when I specify it to the first sheet. The problem is with any other sheet I try to load. I've made sure my excel file is saved, made sure the readxl package is updated, and checked for spelling errors. How do I get readxl to read my specific sheets?

```r
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

PostSurveyData = read_excel("data/GTSurveyCoded with financial status-2.xlsx", 
                                                    sheet = "GTPostSure")
```

Comment: Try `getwd()` to confirm what working directory R is currently set to. (In RStudio you can also go to the Files pane and click More - Go To Working Directory.) That has probably shifted from when you ran the code last, and your code is looking for folders and files relative to your current working directory. You might look at the `here` package for some tools to manage your project directory.

Comment: I'm in the same working directory I've been in since starting this project.

Comment: Hard to help without more details. I might suggest trying to load the file using the RStudio GUI and reviewing what code it outputs to see if there are any differences.